# Seperating concerns in PyQt5 GUI app. Need seperate Qthread for concurrency

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qthread, qtimer

I have a simple GUI window made using PyQt5 Library.

```
 `
 import sys, csv, time
 from datetime import datetime
 from time import strftime,localtime
 import threading
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QLabel, QTextEdit, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
 from PyQt5 import QtCore
 from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
 from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
 from PyQt5 import uic
 from trade import trade
 from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
 import pyqtgraph as pg
 from itertools import islice

class UpdateThread(QThread):
signal = pyqtSignal()
def __init__(self, gui):
    QThread.__init__(self)
    self.gui = gui
def run(self):
    try:
        # timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        # timer.timeout.connect(UI.update_plot(self))
        # timer.start(50)
        while(True):
            self.signal.emit()
            time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

class UI(QMainWindow):
gui = None
p_l = 0.0
display_trades = ''

def __init__(self):
    super(UI, self).__init__()
    global gui
    gui = uic.loadUi('rightside.ui', self)
    self.initUI()
    self.timer_thread = UpdateThread(gui)
    self.timer_thread.signal.connect(self.update_plot)
    self.timer_thread.start()
def initUI(self):
    self.prices = self.read_prices()
    trades = self.get_trades()
    list_trade_prices = trades[0].values.tolist()
    list_trade_sizes = trades[1].values.tolist()
    list_trade_ids = trades[4].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
    as_floats = np.array(list_trade_prices).astype(np.float)
    self.set_fields(self.prices)
    gui.update_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    gui.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.on_exit)
    self.show()
def get_trades(self):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Get 50 most recent trades
    trades = islice(trade.get_product_trades(), 192)
    for x in reversed(list(trades)):
        # if x['trade_id'] > last_id:
        if x['side'] == 'buy':
            #more trades that hit the bid force price down
            new_row = {0:x['price'], 1:x['size'], 2:1, 3:time.mktime(datetime.timetuple(datetime.now())), 4:x['trade_id']}
            df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
            bid_side = True
        else:
            #more trades that hit the offer force force price up
            new_row = {0:x['price'], 1:x['size'], 2:0, 3:time.mktime(datetime.timetuple(datetime.now())), 4:x['trade_id']}
            df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.drop_duplicates([4], keep='last')
    return df
def update_plot(self):
    global gui
    #set results_chart
    trades = UI.get_trades(self)
    list_trade_prices = trades[0].values.tolist()
    last_price = list_trade_prices[-1]
    as_floats = np.array(list_trade_prices).astype(np.float)
    gui.results.setText("{0:,.2f}".format(float(last_price)))
    gui.results_chart.clear()
    gui.results_chart.plot(as_floats)
    gui.statusBar().showMessage('Connected')
    self.monitor_prices(last_price)
    prices = self.read_prices()
    self.set_fields(prices)
def get_open_trades(self, btc):
    sum_buys = 0.0
    open_trades = []
    if float(btc) != 0:
        for i in trade.get_last_fills():
            if i['side'] == 'buy':
                sum_buys += float(i['size'])
                open_trades.append([i['price'], i['size']])
                if sum_buys >= float(btc):
                    break
    return open_trades
def monitor_prices(self, last_price):
    global gui
    date_local = strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", localtime())
    stop_enter_price = float(gui.enter_box.toPlainText())
    usd = gui.usd_display.text().replace(',', '')
    btc = gui.btc_display.text()
    trade_amount = ''
    if float(last_price) > stop_enter_price and stop_enter_price != 0.0:
        if float(usd) > 10.00:
            trade_amount = "{0:.2f}".format((float(usd)+(float(btc)*float(last_price)))*0.02718)
            result = trade.buy_market(trade_amount)
            gui.statusBar().showMessage(str(result))
            gui.enter_box.setText('')
            with open('stop_enter.txt', 'w') as enter:
                enter.write('0.0')
            with open('../trades/buys.csv','a') as buys:
                writer = csv.writer(buys)
                writer.writerow([date_local, last_price, trade_amount, result])
    open_trades = self.get_open_trades(btc)
    display_trades = ''
    trade_amount = 0.0
    total_amount = 0.0
    STOP_RATE = 0.02
    if len(open_trades) != 0:
        highest_entry_price = float(open_trades[0][0])
        lowest_entry_price = float(open_trades[0][0])
        #find lowest price and set stop-loss 2% below that and increment it up
        for i,j in enumerate(open_trades):
            difference = (float(last_price) - float(open_trades[i][0]))*float(open_trades[i][1])
            total_amount += difference
            per_diff = str((float(last_price) - float(open_trades[i][0])) / float(open_trades[i][0]))
            display_trades += f'{"{0:.3f}".format(float(per_diff)*100)}%\t'
            gui.statusBar().showMessage(display_trades)
            if  highest_entry_price < float(open_trades[i][0]):
                highest_entry_price = float(open_trades[i][0])
            if  lowest_entry_price > float(open_trades[i][0]):
                lowest_entry_price = float(open_trades[i][0])
            #1R
            if float(per_diff) < -STOP_RATE:
                if float(btc) > 0.001:
                    trade_amount = "{0:.8f}".format(float(j[1]))
                    response = trade.sell_market(trade_amount)
                    with open('stop_loss.txt', 'w') as enter:
                        enter.write('0.0')
                        gui.statusBar().showMessage(str(response))
    if float(last_price) < float(gui.stop_box.toPlainText()):
        if float(btc) > 0.001:
            trade_amount = "{0:.8f}".format(float(btc))
            response = trade.sell_market(trade_amount)
            gui.statusBar().showMessage(str(response))
def on_click(self):
    global gui
    enter_price = gui.enter_box.toPlainText()
    stop_price = gui.stop_box.toPlainText()
    self.write_prices('stop_enter.txt', enter_price)
    self.write_prices('stop_loss.txt', stop_price)
    gui.statusBar().showMessage('Updated Successfully!')
    time.sleep(1.618)
    gui.statusBar().showMessage('')
def on_exit(self):
    sys.exit(0)
def write_disk(self, date_local, current_price, trade_amount, note, response):
   with open('../trades/sells.csv','a') as sells:
       writer = csv.writer(sells)
       writer.writerow([date_local, current_price, trade_amount, note, response])

def take_it(self, risk_reward, btc):
   if float(btc) > 0.001:
       response = trade.sell_market(btc)
       # playsound(path+'/sounds/sellit.mp3')
       write_disk(date_local, current_price, trade_amount, risk_reward, response)

def write_prices(self, file_name, price):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        file.write(price)
def set_fields(self, prices):
    global gui, p_l
    last_price_data = trade.get_last_price()
    last_price = last_price_data['price']
    last_fill_data = None
    while(True):
        last_fill_data = trade.get_last_fill()
        if 'trade_id' in last_fill_data:
            break
    last_fill = '0.0'
    if last_fill_data['side'] != 'sell':
        last_fill = last_fill_data['price']
    p_l = float(last_price) - float(last_fill)

    gui.enter_box.setText(prices[0])
    gui.stop_box.setText(prices[1])
    gui.results.setText("{0:,.2f}".format(p_l))
    gui.in_price.setText("{0:,.2f}".format(float(last_fill)))
    gui.usd_display.setText("{0:,.2f}".format(float(trade.get_usd())))
    gui.btc_display.setText("{0:,.8f}".format(float(trade.get_btc())))
def read_prices(self):
    content = []
    with open('stop_enter.txt', 'r') as enter:
        stop_enter = enter.readlines()
        content.append(stop_enter[0].rstrip())
    with open('stop_loss.txt', 'r') as stop:
        stop_loss = stop.readlines()
        content.append(stop_loss[0].rstrip())
    return content

 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 ex = UI()
 app.exec_()
```

`
I am not too familiar with qthreads and how to get them to work.  And advice would be greatly appreciated.  I just want to Updatethread to call the update_plot once every like 2 seconds or so.  Thought this would be pretty simple but this is giving me a headache at this point.

I tried putting the Qtimer in the other thread but then I get an error like 'cannot start timer from other thread'

Thanks for all you help my programmer friends.

Comment: That's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

For some timing updates it's better to use [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QTimer.html) and its signal `timeout`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class UI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)

        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.self.update_plot)

        #  Set 2 seconds interval and start the timer
        self.timer.start(2000)

    def update_slot(self):
        #...
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this and it does work as expected, however, this does not solve the concurrency issue, because this whole thread now is being held while this pause is happening and I can not interact with the other GUI components as I need to.  This is why I wanted a separate thread so it doesn't influence the other components.  When I do move this pause function to the other thread, it gives me an error like 'can not start timer from other thread'

Comment: @PhilipCaputo You are correct declare and use QThread (Programmatically not logically) and it seems to me you have some problem with the method update_plot(self): may be it's executed too long. So my advice is to try to measure the time of its executing and may be some of its functions transfer to another thread